# Feature tests not passing REQUEST_URI to a middleware with RSpec and Capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, capybara

I am trying to setup feature testing on an application. 
I decided to install Capybara, and thus added it to my project's Gemfile:

```
group :test do
  gem "capybara"
end
```

I declare my tests on the `spec/feature` folder, and the test manages to execute:

```
require "rails_helper"

feature 'My Feature' do
  scenario 'User visits feature page' do
    visit '/my-feature'
    expect(page).to have_text('Stuff')    
  end
end
```

Issue: I have an URL middleware that does not detect the `env['REQUEST_URI]` flag and thus my test fails:

```
class UrlNormalizationMiddleware

  def initialize(app)
    @app = app
  end


  def call(env)
    uri_items = env['REQUEST_URI'].split('?')
    ...
    @app.call(env)
  end
end
```

The actual application loads, and passes values on `env['REQUEST_URI']`, but doesn't on the test environment.

Anything else that I need to setup?

Thanks!

Comment: Where are you setting values to the REQUEST_URI environment var?  If you're assuming the driver would set then I need to know which driver you're using with Capybara.  rack-test specifically does not set REQUEST_URI because it's not defined in the rack standard - see https://github.com/rack-test/rack-test/issues/26

Comment: I'm not setting it up actually, I read something like that. That means I need to set it up somewhere then, right? Should I make a stub within the test to set it? How do I know which driver I am using with Capybara? Honestly, I just installed capybara and keep using rspecs as usual. If I am missing anything let me know (and if this is the issue make sure you answer so I can mark your answer as correct).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

REQUEST_URI is not part of the rack spec, which means it's not guaranteed to be set, and you shouldn't be using it in your middleware.  Instead you should be using things like PATH_INFO, QUERY_STRING, etc. which are specified in the rack spec and should therefore be available - https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/master/SPEC

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I wasn't too sure about using this approach because I did not want to change the `env['REQUEST_URI']` value everywhere but turns out it is only on two instances.